Why am I getting these KeyErrors using cycles at pandas?
When I created 3 keras models (for 3 different type of data), I'm trying to use these at my big dataset/ I use column 'Rock' to select a model, then I use data from another df (with the same length) to predict a value at column 'Rv_synth'.
df_cut

DEPT    RXOI    SSW TOPS    AT_90   RH39_1DF    RV39_1DF    Rock    GR  ZONES   Rv_synth
68652   3432.60 13.239096   19608.101563    10.0    12.784300   11.323830   29.956650   0.000000    121.453171  1   0
68653   3432.65 28.610432   19782.144531    10.0    14.439166   12.498925   31.454845   0.000000    114.461037  1   0
68654   3432.70 15.997140   19726.130859    10.0    16.094030   13.674020   32.953041   0.000000    107.468910  1   0
68655   3432.75 13.241823   19628.154297    10.0    18.447453   15.684806   35.002056   0.000000    100.766411  1   0
68656   3432.80 12.579830   20877.529297    10.0    20.800871   17.695589   37.051071   0.000000    94.063919   1   0


df_big_X

 RXOI   AT_90   GR
68652   13.239096   12.784300   121.453171
68653   28.610432   14.439166   114.461037
68654   15.997140   16.094030   107.468910
68655   13.241823   18.447453   100.766411
68656   12.579830   20.800871   94.063919
...

But then it shows me these KeyErrors when I run circles:
for i in range(0, len(df_big_X)):
    if df_cut['Rock'][i].array == 1:
        y_pred = model_sand_n.predict(df_big_X[i:i+1])
        df_cut['Rv_synth'][i] = y_pred
    elif df_cut['Rock'][i] == 0:
        y_pred = model_shale_n.predict(df_big_X[i:i+1])
        df_cut['Rv_synth'][i] = y_pred
    elif df_cut['Rock'][i] == 6:
         y_pred = model_cal_n.predict(df_big_X[i:i+1])
         df_cut['Rv_synth'][i] = y_pred       

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\makas\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3791, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3790 try:
-> 3791     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3792 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2606, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2630, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[60], line 2
      1 for i in range(0, len(df_big_X)):
----> 2     if df_cut['Rock'][i].array == 1:
      3         y_pred = model_sand_n.predict(df_big_X[i:i+1])
      4         df_cut['Rv_synth'][i] = y_pred
...
   3801     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3802     #  the TypeError.
   3803     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...

I tried to use df.iloc, but didn't get any results

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A KeyError in pandas usually happens when you try to access a column, row, or index label that doesn’t exist in your DataFrame. Here are some common reasons and solutions:
Typo or Mismatch: Double-check that the name you’re using to access the column/index is correct, including capitalization and any special characters.
Column Not Loaded: If you’re loading data from a CSV or another file, make sure the column actually exists. Sometimes data formats or headers can cause issues.
Chained Operations: When you use chained indexing like df[df["Column"] > 5]["NonexistentColumn"], pandas might lose track of the columns, leading to a KeyError. Try breaking it down or use .loc instead.
Column Dropped or Renamed: If you previously dropped or renamed a column, you won’t be able to access it with the old name. Verify with df.columns to see the current column names.
